# Atom and Hydrogen: Output and console

Tags: atom-editor, hydrogen

I'm a Python beginner and recently came across the `Atom` editor and the package `Hydrogen`, that implements the Jupyter notebook. I did so after realizing that running the notebook in Chrome consumed way too many resources and also seemed to be a bit slower.

However, the Atom editor and Hydrogen always output prints within a little frame in the code (see image). Unfortunately, it doesn't use the full window width. I also don't see any console/terminal for installing pip libraries.

**Is there a way to have the output in a console below the code, just as in Jupyter, and to have a terminal?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

this comes most certainly too late, but in case someone else searches for this:
hit control+shift+P / cmd+shift+P and type "toggle output area".